# Why is not working background-color? - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have made a list with bootstrap and I would like to change the background-color of each item. I have this:

```css
.list-group {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <picture>
      <img class="imagenLista" src="myimage">
    </picture>

    <p>
      <br>sometext
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am using chromium and firefox and I have the same problem, but the curious thing is that in JSBin, it works. I am using sublime text(I don't know if it is important) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target `list-group-item` not `list-group`

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ex03td26/) (with bootstrap imported)

Answer (score 0):

Please add your css to list-group-item

```
.list-group{
background-color: black;
}
a.list-group-item.list-group-item-action {
background-color: #000;
}
```